# Android game, bug when receiving an sms while playing my game

Tags: android, view, sms

When playing my game that I developed, if I receive an SMS, some view will disappear. Does anyone know what it could be linked to ?

Comment: Please read about the Activity life cycle. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: I've already tried to catch every Activity life cycle events (onPause, onResume, onStart, onRestart, onDestroy, ..) but none of them are called when I receive a text..